# Can two different elliptic curves have rational points in common

Tags: elliptic-curves

Can there be two different elliptic curve $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ and two different rational points $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ such that $P_{1}, P_{2} \in E_{1}$ and $P_{1}, P_{2} \in E_{2}$ but $P_{1} + P_{2}$ is a different point for $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$. If so, is it easy for find an example?

Or given two different rational points $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ is there a unique elliptic curve $E$ such that $P_{1}, P_{2} \in E$

Thank you

Comment: How many points determine an elliptic curve in the plane? That might give you a hint about your last question.

Comment: These points are where? In the projective plane? And by elliptic curve you mean in weierstrass form? You should formulate better the question, shouldn't you? 

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez no idea, where could I find that info

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Let $E_1$ be the curve defined by the equation $y^2=x(x-1)(x-2)$ and $E_2$ be the curve $y^2=x(x-1)(x-3)$. Let $P_1=(0,0)$ and $P_2=(1,0)$. These points are certainly on both curves.

On $E_1$, $P_1+P_2=(2,0)$ but on $E_2$ it's $(3,0)$. (Assuming that the point at infinity is the identity.)

In fact, there is a unique elliptic curve passing through every $9$ points in general position.